# How to convert the date format in unix

Tags: unix

Let me explain the problem
I stored a variable like `Date_1="Wed Dec 25 06:35:02 EST 2013"`

I want the output as `"2013-12-25 06:35:02"`

I tried with date command.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date_1="Wed Dec 25 06:35:02 EST 2013"
TZ=UTC+5 date -d "${Date_1}" "+%Y-%m-%d %T"
```

Result :

```
2013-12-25 06:35:02
```

Don't use TZ, if dates in input and output are in the same timezone, but just: `date -d "${Date_1}" "+%Y-%m-%d %T"`